# Terence Tao's definition of subtraction operation to build integers

Tags: real-analysis, integers

I am reading the book Analysis 1 by Terence Tao in which he discussed the construction of integers from natural numbers. The integers are constructed from the natural numbers by the operation $subtraction$.

To be able to define the $subtraction$ operation, he started with the "$--$" symbol as a placeholder and then he defined the subtraction operation based on that symbol.

I interpret his definition of integer (shown in the picture) like this: We have the expression $a$ $--$ $b$, then we call that expression an integer. By saying "we have" means we know for sure the expression has already existed.

However, the symbol "$--$" has never been defined. We don't even know whether if exists or not and don't know what it means to be.

**So my question is: How can we define the new term "integer" based on something which is also "new" (in this case, the symbol "$--$")**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Think of the symbol $a$--$b$ to mean simply $(a,b)$. Parentheses are also "new" in this sense. The $--$ is simply there to distinguish the two natural numbers.

Comment: See [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893642/terence-tao-analysis-i-on-defining-subtraction-operation-problem)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: thanks for your response. I have already read the post but I does not quite response to my question.

Comment: But the issue is the same: we *define* a new "object" the pair of naturals $(a,b)$ and we *name* it: INTEGER. The idea works because we prove that the new object satisfies the expected ruoles for integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the relation

$(a,b)\sim (c,d) :\Longleftrightarrow a+d=b+d$.

This relation is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb N_0^2$, so we can form equivalence classes and the quotient set.

The equivalence class of $(a,b)$ denoted $a--b$ is the set of all pairs that are equivalent to $(a,b)$.

The set of equivalence classes $\{a--b\mid a,b\in\Bbb N_0\}$
is called $\Bbb Z$ and defines the set of integers.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. Technically, the use of a placeholder symbol like this is somewhat of a loose construction of the integers. What Tao means, formally, is that we are defining an *equivalence relation* on the Cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, where two elements $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ are considered to be equal if and only if $a + d = c + b$. In other words, an integer is simply a pair of natural numbers. We compare integers and consider them to be equal to each other using the rule $a + d = c + b$. The use of the symbol $a--b$ is simply a shorthand for $(a, b)$, as he (probably) is just trying to get his readers to understand the motivation behind such a construction i.e. it's to imitate the rules of subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely syntactic definition.  First, '--' is introduced, then (I suspect this step is done implicitly) purely syntactic expressions of the form 'a--b' (for a and b being natural numbers) are defined based on the existing definition of '--', then the above definition is introduced.